# Joomla custom link

Tags: php, joomla, hyperlink

Ok I have a three tier menu and have SEF links turned on. I have a link like this http://www.site.com/something/column/banning. How would I get it to be like this http://www.site.com/banning, without changing the menus structure

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible by default, as an admin. You will either have to create your own plugin/extension or change the code, or install an extension which allows you to manage and map URIs like [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134). See the [SEF category at Joomla Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef).